# Java library for text analysis and counts

Tags: java, jar, word-count

I need a stable Java library that I can pass a huge string to (e.g., a few chapters from *Moby Dick*) and get "word count"-like stats:

- Number of paragraphs
- Number of sentences
- Number of words
- Number of characters

Preferably something internationalizable/localizable but not required. I figured Apache Commons would have something like this, but after a thorough search it does not.

I could write this myself but it would probably be buggy and take a lot of time; plus I don't want to reinvent the wheel if it already exists. I am thinking of using Apache Tika but cannot confirm if it will do what I need. It seems to handle word count, but not the others. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Recommendation questions aren't really appropriate for SO.

Comment: OK - @millimoose I edited the question to address Apache Tika specifically.

Comment: And @JBNizet my choice of the word "instantly" was unfortunate. I was not implying constant time, I was using it as a colloquialism. I have removed it from the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at Apache Tika. It might serve your requirements

Comment: Thanks @AmithKoujalgi (+1) - it looks like Tika is an executable JAR that needs to run from the command line? Is this true, or can it function just like any other (non-executable) jar lib? Thanks again!

Comment: @DirtyMikeAndTheBoys: That's not what the "Getting started", the "Parser API" and all the other links in the home page of the project say. Take some time to read.

Comment: P1: "*Is this Coca Cola, or Pepsi?*" P2: (No answer). P1: "*Obviously it is Pepsi.*" P2: "*No P1, RTFM and you'll see it's not Pepsi*". P1: "*Then it must be Coca Cola! Eureka, I have my answer!*"

Comment: You can not only run it from commandline, you can even run it from the code. Take a look at this. http://blog.vigneshwaran.in/java-program-using-apache-tika-to-extract-tex

Comment: A great thing about Tika is it can read any type of file/document and it automatically analyses encoding and formats it to a readable string